# Distance between countertop power outlet and gas range

Tags: electrical

Is there a minimum distance between a gas range and a power outlet? My logic for concern is that a power cord close to a gas range can catch on the flames from the range. E.g. is 9" diagonal from the range okay, 6" lateral distance.

Please note this is not the outlet to power the range but just a countertop receptacle.

Comment: How is the cord getting anywhere near the rangetop to begin with?

Comment: I'm just playing devil's advocate. I already made one pretty huge and expensive mistake positioning a gas range next to what was supposed to be a window and had to board up the window because it's against the code (wind can fan the flames on the stove). So I'm extra cautious. I'm doing design but I don't really know the code.

Comment: Some electric ranges had outlets, often timer-controlled. Not sure if any are still made.

Comment: Is the question about (a) the receptacle to power the range or (b) a countertop receptacle to be used for other stuff (mixer, toaster, etc.)?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact good question, just a countertop receptacle.

Comment: Our gas range had an electric outlet actually on it, (i.e. built into it, I suppose so you had a handy place for the portable mixer if mixing in a pot being heated) to the best of my recall.

Comment: Not an Answer because I think the question is about Code but in practice I'd try to keep a backsplash outlet at least 12 inches laterally from a range if space allows, so that the backsplash near the range, which tends to get oily and dirty, can be cleaned easily with spray cleaners, wet rags, etc without having to negotiate a live outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Code doesn’t restrict the location of a range receptacle. They are normally behind the range location most are below the counter height so the receptacle is not visible when the range is in place. The builder has no idea what range may be used in most cases.

Added to be more specific; the location of countertop receptacles is not restricted other than there must be one within 2’ of counter space or 4’ between. The receptacle can be mounted adjacent to a stove cut out and or adjacent to a sink location but there are no restrictions the same as the location of the receptacle behind the stove if one is installed.

Comment: This addresses the question of where the outlet that the range itself plugs into should go. However, the OP's question is about where a mandatory counter-top outlet for small kitchen appliances should be. His concern is if the blender is plugged into the outlet and the cord for the blender gets too close to the gas stove & melts the cord.

Comment: @freeman, that may be your opinion but not what the question asks: if there is a concern the op should not plug that device in there but a receptacle is required within 2’ of the edge of the counter top and normally one installed directly behind the oven there is no restriction as I said and that was what the question asked.

Comment: The last sentence of the OP: "Please note this is not the outlet to power the range but just a countertop receptacle." More than just opinion

Comment: @Freeman since the question was edited after my answer that could have been added after my answer as the early comments show. Maybe we should work at purging hanging questions than second guessing edited questions.

Comment: Fair enough - I hadn't noticed the time stamps.